# TCPDF and alignment of pagenumber(s) in table

Tags: tcpdf

I am using TCPDF with the following code:

```
    require_once('TCPDF/tcpdf.php');

    $pdf = new TCPDF();

    $html = '<table>';

    $html .= '<tr><td style="text-align:left;">Order-No.:</td><td>OF16-110074</td></tr>';

    $html .= '<tr><td style="text-align:left;">Your Ref:</td><td>YREF01234</td></tr>';

    $html .= '<tr><td style="text-align:left;">Page / Pages:</td><td>';
    $html .= $pdf->getAliasNumPage() . " / " . $pdf->getAliasNbPages(); 
    $html .= '</td></tr>';

    $html .= '<tr><td style="text-align:left;">Page:</td><td>';
    $html .= $pdf->getAliasNumPage();
    $html .= '</td></tr>';

    $html .= '<tr><td style="text-align:left;">Our Ref:</td><td>MREF56789</td></tr>';
    $html .= '</table>';

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(100, 0, 75, 30, $html, null, 0, false, true, "R");

    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    $pdf->Output();
```

So all right cells are aligned right, except the cell containing page number. Also I tried with style="text-align:right"; but it does not help.

How can I align cells containing pagenumber?

Regards
Bytecounter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr><td align="right">
```